Why Field Injection makes NullPointException
Im studying about dependency injections in Spring.
this is example of field injection.
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @Autowired private  MemberRepository memberRepository;
    @Autowired private  DiscountPolicy discountPolicy;

    @Override
    public Order createOrder(Long memberId, String itemName, int itemPrice) {
        Member member = memberRepository.findById(memberId);
        int discountPrice = discountPolicy.discount(member, itemPrice);

        return new Order(memberId, itemName, itemPrice, discountPrice);
    }
    
    //for test
    public MemberRepository getMemberRepository() {
        return memberRepository;
    }

and I tested it
OrderServiceImpl bean = ac.getBean(OrderServiceImpl.class);
MemberRepository memberRepository = bean.getMemberRepository();
System.out.println("memberRepository = " + memberRepository);

and this worked, I checked MemoryMemberRepository was injected to memberRepository.
and I tried another test.
    @Test
    void fieldInjectionTest() {
        OrderServiceImpl orderService = new OrderServiceImpl();

        orderService.createOrder(1L, "itemA", 10000);
    }

and this test was failed because memberRepository was Null.
I can understand.
In the first test, I saw the instance of memberRepository is genenrated.
But in the second test, the result say memberRepository is null.
To make success in the second test, I had to use setter.
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @Autowired private  MemberRepository memberRepository;
    @Autowired private  DiscountPolicy discountPolicy;

    public void setMemberRepository(MemberRepository memberRepository) {
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
    }

    public void setDiscountPolicy(DiscountPolicy discountPolicy) {
        this.discountPolicy = discountPolicy;
    }

    @Override
    public Order createOrder(Long memberId, String itemName, int itemPrice) {
        Member member = memberRepository.findById(memberId);
        int discountPrice = discountPolicy.discount(member, itemPrice);

        return new Order(memberId, itemName, itemPrice, discountPrice);
    }
    
    //for test
    public MemberRepository getMemberRepository() {
        return memberRepository;
    }

Add setters in OrderServiceImpl
    @Test
    void fieldInjectionTest() {
        OrderServiceImpl orderService = new OrderServiceImpl();

        orderService.setMemberRepository(new MemoryMemberRepository());
        orderService.setDiscountPolicy(new FixDiscountPolicy());

        orderService.createOrder(1L, "itemA", 10000);
    }

and modify the second test like this.
of course there are some errors like there is no member class instance etc..
I can understands that errors, that errors is easy errors.
But still I can understand why in the origin second test, the memberRepository was null
I wanna know why field injection makes NPE.
In my head, memberRepository should not be null.
I wanna know why.

Field injection only works when you ask the dependency injection framework for an instance.
In the first test you do it:
OrderServiceImpl bean = ac.getBean(OrderServiceImpl.class);

But in the second test you are creating an OrderServiceImpl instance yourself:
OrderServiceImpl orderService = new OrderServiceImpl();

The dependency injection framework doesn't know anything about this instance and therefore cannot do field injection and that means that you need to set the dependencies yourself.

This is one of the reasons why field injection is discouraged.
When using constructor injection (where the dependencies are provided as constructor arguments) the first test would look the same:
OrderServiceImpl bean = ac.getBean(OrderServiceImpl.class);

But for the second test to compile you would need to provide the dependencies yourself:
OrderServiceImpl orderService = new OrderServiceImpl(
    new MemoryMemberRepository(), 
    new FixDiscountPolicy()
);

And the OrderServiceImpl would look like this
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    private  MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private  DiscountPolicy discountPolicy;

    public OrderServiceImpl(MemberRepository memberRepository, DiscountPolicy discountPolicy) {
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
        this.discountPolicy = discountPolicy;
    }


You should annotate your OrderServiceImpl by @Component  annotation then only IOC container will able to create bean of MemberRepository and DiscountPolicy.
your code should look like
@Component
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
@Autowired private  MemberRepository memberRepository;
@Autowired private  DiscountPolicy discountPolicy;

@Override
public Order createOrder(Long memberId, String itemName, int itemPrice) {
    Member member = memberRepository.findById(memberId);
    int discountPrice = discountPolicy.discount(member, itemPrice);

    return new Order(memberId, itemName, itemPrice, discountPrice);
}

//for test
public MemberRepository getMemberRepository() {
    return memberRepository;
}

}
